# How to approximate the probability distribution of a lot of die throws?

Tags: probability

We throw a die 10000 times and record the sum of the outcomes. How could I approximate the probability, that the sum is in the range of 34500 - 35500?

Comment: You approximate it. Also welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I have already count the mean and standard deviation but i don’t understand how to fix it

Comment: What are you wanting to fix?

Comment: the probability. I’ve searched the reference and it should use Excel. but i want know how to fix it manually

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you have the sum of *many* probabilities, in any distribution, you can calculate it as if it would be the sum of [normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with the same expected value and [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

Thus,

1. You calculate the expected value and the standard deviation of a single die throw
2. You sum up 10000 normal distributions with the same deviation and expected value.

You have simple formulas for all of them, you only need to substitute things.

Comment: thank you. i got it